# Maven - Como adicionar um diretório no build?

Tags: maven, pom

Estou com dificuldade em adicionar um **diretório** do meu projeto dentro do arquivo ***.jar**.

Adicionei o código abaixo no meu **pom.xml** :

```
      <resource>               
            <directory>migration/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.sql</include>
            </includes>
      </resource>
```

Só que assim inclui somente os arquivos *.sql* e não adiciona o diretório "**migration**"

Estrutura do projeto abaixo:

```
 + meuprojeto
 |---src/main/java
 |---src/test/java
 |---Maven Dependencies
 |---migration
```

Comment: Você deseja fazer isso para o Flyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) já provê uma estrutura padrão para você por arquivos de recursos não código. O local para isso é em `src/main/resources/` para código de produção e `src/test/resources/` para teste. O Maven vai conseguir por tudo no classpath.

Para o seu caso, basta por a pasta `migration` e seu conteúdo assim:

```
+ meuprojeto
 |---src/main/java
 |---src/main/resources/migration
 |---src/test/java
 |---Maven Dependencies
```

Já testei isso em um webservice usando Flyway para a migração do banco de dados embarcado.

Se estiver usando Eclipse, a IDE pode implicar um pouco. Talvez a opção `update Maven project` <kbd>ALT+F5</kbd> resolva. Outra alternativa: clique com o botão direito sobre o diretório `src/main/resources` e selecione `add to build path`. Por fim, a última alternativa que imagino é: delete o projeto do Eclipse (mantenha o conteúdo em disco) e então manda importar um projeto Maven novamente.